# How to decompress data using z lib in symbian

Tags: symbian, compression

I have compressed a data using Deflater(Z lib) in java. My friend is in symbian he is using 
z lib. But he is unable to decompress the data.
But if he compress the data then i am able to decompress the data

Is there any compression level to be set by me so that the can be decompressed by the symbian guy.

Or is there any help to implement decompression using z lib in symbian.

Is there any way to solve this problem

Thanks sunil

Comment: homework? duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1037835/decompression-using-zlib-of-string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/975777/how-to-create-compression-decompression-program-using-gzip-in-symbian

Comment: I do not think its duplicate stackoverflow.com/questions/975777/…
pls have a look on this url that u have mention. Also I have mentioned about compression level. Can you go through query once again. I want to know about compression level of the data which can be decompressed by symbian.

Comment: Its not homework for me may be it for you as you may know the answer.
But its a  nightmare for me. As per my knowledge concern No one does this type of home work. Please provide any answer if you have.

Comment: @sunil: People here are not psychics who can read your mind and code at a distance. You need to provide detailed information about what you have attempted and where it is failing. In particular, post code snippets.

Comment: No people have to read what ever they get as information and think about it thats why we are human being.

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is to do a comparison of encryption/decryption methods on both the Java and Symbian side.

What I would do is create some data, encrypt it on the Java side and save it to a file - check that you can decrypt this on the Java side - verify that the decryption worked by comparing it to the original content.

Do the same on the Symbian side. This will at least validate that you can encrypt/decrypt the data on either side in isolation.

Assuming this is successful, next I would do a diff on the encrypted binaries - if they're using the same encryption method they should be the same - but it sounds like they won't be. I'd recommend using a tool like vimdiff to do the binary diff.

Inspect the binary dump of both of the encrypted files. If the binaries are different you will need to do some research on the zlib compression format - usually binary data formats have headers, although there can be raw modes which assume you know the format of the data.